# Import all variables from another module(s) into dictionary python

Tags: python

Is there a "built-in" way of importing variables from another module into dictionary in python instead of parsing the module and manually creating the dictionary? I am looking for something similar to:

```
from myVars import*
d = globals()
```

However, the approach above puts all variables (from local module and the imported module) and also includes some system vars like _ *file* _, _ *main* _ etc. which I do not want to be in the dictionary.

Given that *myVars.py* has the following content:

```
myvar1 = "Hello "
myvar2 = "world"
myvar3 = myvar1 + myvar2
```

I would like to have only those variables put into the dictionary when I run *script.py*:

```
from myVars import*
d = someMagicalVariableExtractionFuntion()
print(d)
```

would give me this:

```
{'myvar1': 'Hello ','myvar2': 'world','myvar3': 'Hello world'}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use `vars`?

```
>>> import pprint
>>> import math
>>> pprint.pprint(vars(math))
{'__doc__': 'This module is always available.  It provides access to the\nmathematical functions defined by the C standard.',
 '__file__': '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/math.so',
 '__name__': 'math',
 '__package__': None,
 'acos': <built-in function acos>,
    ... <snip> ...
 'sinh': <built-in function sinh>,
 'sqrt': <built-in function sqrt>,
 'tan': <built-in function tan>,
 'tanh': <built-in function tanh>,
 'trunc': <built-in function trunc>}
```

If you want to filter out some special values, there are some options.

If control both sides, you can add an `__all__` to the module being imported from to control `import *`.

If you want to get rid of magic values, you can enumerate them, or drop them by pattern:

```
excluded = set(['worst_value', '_bobs_my_uncle', 'xxx_secret_xxx'])
bad = lambda k: k in excluded or k.startswith('__')
d = {k: v for k, v in something.items() if not bad(k)}
```

Comment: I tried `import myVars` `d = vars(myVars)` `print(d)` and I got a ton of variables printed and only at the end the three I needed. So far, `globals()` works better. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: When I tried to reproduce I can see the `__builtins__` from your module.  If you filter out `__` / `_` prefixed-values you should be fine, e.g.: `pprint.pprint({k: v for k, v in vars(my_vars).items() if not k.startswith('_')})`

Comment: This is exactly what has been done by import: "If the list of identifiers is replaced by a star ("*"), all names defined in the module are bound, except those beginning with an underscore ("_")".  https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/import.html